# Laravel 5.1 server does not start

Tags: laravel-5, server, laravel-5.1

I have successfully uploaded my project files to server in root directory and when I write:

```
php artisan serve
```

on putty to start the server, it do says:

> Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000/

But has no effect on project, home does not get loaded, instead shows the list of files and folders on laravel.
but when I run the command

```
php artisan serve --host mydomainName.com
```

it says:

> Laravel development server started on http://mydomainName.com:8000/

And when I open that URL in the browser, the website gets start working, but now I have to use the port 8000, everytime I have to open my website, I know default port is 80, but server dose not listen to it, says not enough permissions.

Comment: Are you trying to use `php artisan serve` on a live/production server? That command should only be used for local development.

Comment: And for the production site, you dont have to run the server using php artisan.

Answer (score 0):

If you use wamp server create folder in www directory.
and copy all file and folder in this folder.
for example `test` drectory

```
c:\wamp\www\test\*.*
```

and in browser you can access them like this

```
localhost\test\public
```

and if you you xampp copy in htdocs folders

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\test\*.*
```

> Note: in apache must be `mod_rewrite=on`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 php artisan up
```

or restart your apache server